# How to access a public array inside a function in the same PHP object? Array returns NULL

Tags: php, arrays, function, object

I'm writing a function in an object and need to access an array that gets constructed when the object is created. I can access normal variables inside the function using `$this->var` but I can't access an array in the same way using `$this->array['key']`. Why can't my function use arrays?

Here's the offending code:

```
class User
{
    public $_x;
    public $_y;
    public $_z;
    public $_array;

    public function __construct($username)
    {
        $_x = 'a';
        $_y = 'b';
        $_z = 'c';
        $_array = array( 'red' => $_x,  'blue' => $_y,  'green' => $_z,);
    }

    public function myFunction()
    {
        echo $this->_x . "<br>";
        echo $this->_y . "<br>";
        echo $this->_z . "<br>";
        echo $this->_array['red'] . "<br>";
        echo $this->_array['blue'] . "<br>";
        echo $this->_array['green'] . "<br>";
        var_dump($this->_array);
    }
}

$user = new User;
$user->myFunction();
```

Which displays:

a

b

c

NULL

Comment: Are you sure about that output?

Answer (score 1):

You forgot `$this`:

```
public function __construct($username)
{
    $_x = 'a';  // LOCAL variable, exists only in the constructor
    $this->_x = 'a'; // class variable
    ^^^^^----you forgot this
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `$this` keyword in the constructor too:

```
public function __construct($username)
{
    $this->_x = 'a';
    $this->_y = 'b';
    $this->_z = 'c';
    $this->_array = array( 'red' => $this->_x,  'blue' => $this->_y,  'green' => $this->_z,);
}
```

Comment: Now $_x, $_y and $z are not defined for the array definition.